# Not able to loop through JSON object on table in Angular 6

Tags: html, json, angular, loops, typescript

I have JSON Object as below received from GET REST call.

```
[
{
    "driverName": "Bob",
    "customerName": "-",
    "status": "AVAILABLE"
},
{
    "driverName": "Harry",
    "customerName": "-",
    "status": "AVAILABLE"
},
{
    "driverName": "Peter",
    "customerName": "-",
    "status": "AVAILABLE"
},
{
    "driverName": "John",
    "customerName": "-",
    "status": "AVAILABLE"
},
{
    "driverName": "Rob",
    "customerName": "-",
    "status": "AVAILABLE"
}
```

]

I want to iterate on this and display them all in table format.
I have my code for this is as below.

AppComponent.ts

```
driverStatusResponse: any[] = [];
```

AppService.ts

```
getDriverStatus():Observable<any>{
var httpUrl = this.baseURL+"driverstatus/";
  return this._http.get(httpUrl)
        .pipe(map((response: Response) => <any> response.text()));

}
```

And component's html :

```
<tbody bgcolor="#b3ecff">
    <tr *ngFor="let driver of driverStatusResponse">
      <td>{{driver.driverName}}</td>
      <td>{{driver.customerName}}</td>
      <td>{{driver.status}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

I am getting error in console as below :

```
AppComponent.html:24 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[{"driverName":"Bob","customerName":"kushhs","status":"BUSY"},{"driverName":"Harry","customerName":"aSdjb","status":"BUSY"},{"driverName":"Peter","customerName":"aSdjb","status":"BUSY"},{"driverName":"John","customerName":"zdgf","status":"BUSY"},{"driverName":"Rob","customerName":"asdfsg","status":"BUSY"}]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
at DefaultIterableDiffer.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.js:6194)
at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3386)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:10100)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:11363)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:11325)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11962)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11922)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:35)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11914)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11307)
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Do you retrieve the JSON object from request or you are defining it ?

Comment: I retrieved it from request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out different things with the code, I found an answer.
The mistake was in the service call. The modified code that gives the correct array to iterate on it is,

```
getDriverStatus():Observable<any[]>{
    var httpUrl = this.baseURL+"driverstatus/";
      return this._http.get(httpUrl)
            .pipe(map((response: Response) => <any[]> response.json()));
}
```

This gives response body as json array.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your HTTP API is returning an object {} - ngFor requires an array [] to iterate.

Change your API to produce an array, or transform the object in your component.

Take a look if you API response start with {}.

**OBJECT**

```
{[
    {
        driverName: "John",
        customerName: "-",
        status: "AVAILABLE"
    }    
]}
```

**ARRAY**

```
[{
   driverName: "John",
   customerName: "-",
   status: "AVAILABLE"
}]
```

Comment: my response starts with [], that means it is sending array, right?

Comment: Yes it is, Could you print in console console.log(driverStatusResponse)  when you receive the response to check the object structure.

Comment: Yes, I have already printed it in console and I am getting the same what I have posted here at the begining

Comment: I don't know if it works but try to remove the "" QUOTES  in the property objects like my  example